# Docusign run code grant steps programmatically in node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docusignapi

New to docusign and have been reading the docs, and I can't seem to get around these problems.

Per the docs it says that gets a code getAuthorizationUri() which can then be used by generateAccessToken() to get a token. After that, the token can be used to explore the API with other methods.

I'm stuck in two places: First I configured my get Authorization like this (typescript)

```
import { ApiClient } from 'docusign-esign'
const apiClient = new ApiClient()
const url: string = apiClient.getAuthorizationUri(
        config.docusign.INTERGRATION_KEY,
        ['signature'],
        'http://localhost/',
        'code',
        'ready'
    )
console.log(url)
```

I get the url fine, but it is always starts with acccounts.docusign as opposed to the required account-d.docusign that's required because my app is in dev.

Secondly, I can't figure out how to transition that URL into a code programtically. Yes, I can copy and paste it from the browser URL (as in the instruction videos), but obviously my next step is to run something like:

```
async getToken(authCode){
  const token = await apiClient.generateAccessToken(
INTERGRATION_KEY,
SECRET_KEY,
authCode
)
console.log(token)
return token
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change authentication from prod to demo, you need to make this call:

```
apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
```

You may also want to change the URL for API calls if you use this later like this:

```
apiClient.setBasePath("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
```

I suggest using an OAuth npm package and not doing this yourself.
See how it's done in the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) (Pick Node.js and Auth Code Grant)

Comment: Thanks. I did download a quick start already to try to understand how these two methods work together. I didn't find them called though.